# How to filter screen_view analytics based on screen title on GA?

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm developing a Flutter application and collecting analytics using [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics). I have configured `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` in my app so I'm getting screen_view analytics in GA.

[image]

Is it possible to filter screen_view analytics based on specific screen titles? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see detailed information about screen_view based on screen title, go to `page and screens` -> scroll down and filter on `Page title and screen name`.

[image]